# convert a string of "0x00... " into bytearray in python

Tags: python, hex, pyserial

i'd like to send hex codes through my COM port in order to drive an engine.
I have all the hexadecimal codes in a .txt that i open using this method (https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/convertir-fichier-tableur-csv-en-liste-sur-python, in french). This gives me a list of hex codes:

- Code[0] = "0X53,0X0B,0X01,0X02,0XFF,0X60,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0XC2,0X45"

The issue is to send that code through my com port. Using  `ser.write(bytearray([0X53,0X0B,0X01,0X02,0XFF,0X60,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0XC2,0X45]));`

works but i have to input manually the hex code. I'd like to extract the line from the .txt and send it through the COM port
Here's my code at the moment

```
    import serial
import csv
 
def convertisseur(chemin):
    Tableau = []
    Temps = []
    Acc = []

    f = open(chemin)
    csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    for row in f:
        Tableau.append(row)
    
    f.close

    n = len(Tableau)
    for i in range(n-1):
        Temps.append(Tableau[i][0])
        Acc.append(Tableau[i][1])
             
    return (Tableau)

def main():
        print("TEST DE PySerial")
        print("----------------")
        print
        ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=1)
        ser.close()
        ser.open()
        ser.write(bytearray([0X53,0X0B,0X01,0X02,0XFF,0X60,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0XC2,0X45]));
        
        Code=convertisseur('C:/Users/Tdeba/Desktop/Cod.txt')
        ser.write(Code[0].encode())
        print(Code[0].encode())
        #ser.write(bytearray([0X53,0X0B,0X01,0X02,0XFF,0X60,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0XC2,0X45]));
        ser.close()
        return   0
    

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    
    main()
```

Comment: `bytearray(int(i, 16) for i in s.split(","))`

Comment: Thanks alot it worked ! 
ser.write(bytearray(int(i, 16) for i in Code[0].split(",")))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass generator into `bytearray` constructor:

```
bytearray(int(i, 16) for i in s.split(","))
```